# Implementing very slow external drive using ESP32 and TinyUSB

Tags: esp32, usb, esp

I want to implement a simple external drive with ESP32-S3 that would act like a normal USB enabled flash drive when connected to a computer.

The actual storage of the data is done mechanically (for educational purposes) and controlled via the esp pins. (the exact setup is not important now)

I am using the esp32TinyUSB library to implement the communication between the ESP and the Computer. However the problem is, that when I actually try to store the data using the mechanical system (**which is very slow ~1 bit/s**), the USB disconnects from the computer.

Is there a way to fix this issue? I don't know how exactly the USB and MSC protocol works but I am thinking some keep-alive messages?

Here is the `setup()` which is typical for this library:

```cpp
void setup() {
  USB.onEvent(usbEventCallback);
  MSC.vendorID("myUSB");
  MSC.productID("myUSB");
  MSC.productRevision("1.0");
  MSC.onStartStop(onStartStop);
  MSC.onRead(onRead);
  MSC.onWrite(onWrite);
  MSC.mediaPresent(true);
  MSC.begin(DISK_SECTOR_COUNT, DISK_SECTOR_SIZE);
  USBSerial.begin();
  USB.begin();
}
```

and here is where the problem lies:

```cpp
static int32_t onWrite(uint32_t lba, uint32_t offset, uint8_t* buffer, uint32_t bufsize){
  // this check is there to only use the mechanical system of storage for 
  //one of the segments
  if (lba == 8) { 
    for(int i = 0; i < bufsize; i++) {
      writeAt(offset + i, buffer[i]); // this function is slow and probably causing problems
    }
  } else {
    memcpy(msc_disk[lba] + offset, buffer, bufsize); // otherwise store in memory
  }
  return bufsize;
}
```

thank you in advance!

UPDATE:

I later found, that the reason for the drive disconnecting is probably the fact, that the esp32 is not dealing with the interrupts (events) as fast as they are coming from the USB (which is unfortunately unavoidable). This probably causes the ESP32 to be overwelmed with the events to the point that it crashes.

I will have to come up with a queue in memory that will be holding the waiting events. It seems like there is nothing like keep-alive messages on this layer - the Windows OS just waits patiently and displays the loading bar...